# How can I match country names when there is a bilateral dataset?

Tags: pandas, merge

My aim is to merge datasets. However, I am not sure how I can do it since bilateral datasets have two country columns. Especially matching country names is confusing having two columns for country names for the df2. I need to use the index ("v2x_regime") for both columns.

df1:

| country_name | Year | v2x_regime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Turkiye | 1993 | 0 |
| Turkiye | 1994 | 0 |
| Turkiye | 1995 | 1 |
| Italy | 1993 | 1 |
| Spain | 1993 | 0 |
| Germany | 1993 | 1 |
| Russia | 1993 | 0 |
| Russia | 1995 | 0 |
| USA | 1993 | 1 |

df2:

| Reporting Country | Partner Country | Year | FDI_outward |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Turkiye | Italy | 1993 | 132 |
| Turkiye | Italy | 1994 | 392 |
| Italy | Turkiye | 1993 | 913 |
| Ukrain | Germany | 1993 | 512 |
| Germany | Russia | 1993 | 714 |
| Russia | Germany | 1993 | 451 |
| Russia | Germany | 1995 | 282 |
| USA | UK | 1993 | 1241 |

So I would like to have the final dataset as follows:

| Reporting Country | v2x_regime_reporting | Partener Country | v2x_regime_partner | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Italy | 1 | Russia | 0 | 1990 |
| Italy | 1 | Russia | 0 | 1991 |
| Italy | 1 | US | 1 | 1990 |
| US | 1 | UK | 1 | 1990 |
| US | 1 | Russia | 0 | 1990 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "country_name": [
            "Turkiye",
            "Turkiye",
            "Turkiye",
            "Italy",
            "Spain",
            "Germany",
            "Russia",
            "Russia",
            "USA",
        ],
        "year": [1993, 1994, 1995, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1995, 1993],
        "v2x_regime": [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "reporting_country": [
            "Turkiye",
            "Turkiye",
            "Italy",
            "Ukrain",
            "Germany",
            "Russia",
            "Russia",
            "USA",
        ],
        "partner_country": [
            "Italy",
            "Italy",
            "Turkiye",
            "Germany",
            "Russia",
            "Germany",
            "Germany",
            "UK",
        ],
        "year": [1993, 1994, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1995, 1993],
    }
)
```

```py
print(df1)
# Output
  country_name  year  v2x_regime
0      Turkiye  1993           0
1      Turkiye  1994           0
2      Turkiye  1995           1
3        Italy  1993           1
4        Spain  1993           0
5      Germany  1993           1
6       Russia  1993           0
7       Russia  1995           0
8          USA  1993           1

print(df2)
# Output
  reporting_country partner_country  year
0         Turkiye             Italy  1993
1         Turkiye             Italy  1994
2           Italy           Turkiye  1993
3          Ukrain           Germany  1993
4         Germany            Russia  1993
5          Russia           Germany  1993
6          Russia           Germany  1995
7             USA                UK  1993
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
# Find matching values
for col in ["reporting_country", "partner_country"]:
    df2[f"v2x_regime_{col}"] = df2.apply(
        lambda x: df1.loc[
            (df1["year"] == x["year"]) & (df1["country_name"] == x[col]), "v2x_regime"
        ].values,
        axis=1,
    )
    df2[f"v2x_regime_{col}"] = df2[f"v2x_regime_{col}"].apply(
        lambda x: x[0] if len(x) > 0 else pd.NA
    )

# Reorder columns
df2 = df2.reindex(
    columns=[
        "reporting_country",
        "v2x_regime_reporting_country",
        "partner_country",
        "v2x_regime_partner_country",
        "year",
    ]
)
```

```py
print(df2)
# Output
  reporting_country v2x_regime_reporting_country partner_country  \
0         Turkiye                 0                        Italy   
1         Turkiye                 0                        Italy   
2           Italy                 1                      Turkiye   
3          Ukrain              <NA>                      Germany   
4         Germany                 1                       Russia   
5          Russia                 0                      Germany   
6          Russia                 0                      Germany   
7             USA                 1                           UK   

  v2x_regime_partner_country  year  
0               1             1993  
1            <NA>             1994  
2               0             1993  
3               1             1993  
4               0             1993  
5               1             1993  
6            <NA>             1995  
7            <NA>             1993
```